# Firebird ADO.NET

Tags: c#, firebird, ado.net

Atualizei o "Firebird ADO.NET Data provider" para a versão 4.10.0 e estou recebendo, ás vezes, a seguinte exceção na minha aplicação.

```
Exception information: 
    Exception type: NullReferenceException 
    Exception message: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at FirebirdSql.Data.Common.Extensions.TryGetTarget[T](WeakReference  weakReference, T& target)
   at FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FbConnectionInternal.RemovePreparedCommand    (FbCommand command)
   at FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FbCommand.Release()
   at FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FbCommand.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
```

Antes da atualização esta exceção não era disparada.

Comment: Não é problema de atualização, isto é erro de programação. Eu sei que vai dizer que antes não acontecia. Era coincidência não acontecer. Precisaria do código e o local exato para analisar.

Comment: @bigown, o problema é que ocorre bem esporadicamente e nem sempre nas mesmas funcionalidades. E como você pode afirmar que não é um erro da dll do firebird?

Comment: No máximo é o fato de eles terem deixado essa exceção ocorrer, mas ela ocorre só se você passar coisas que não pode. O esporádico é que cada vez executada dentro de um padrão diferente. Este é o pior tipo de erro que tem, você não consegue saber porque está ocorrendo. Por isso é importante fazer certo desde o início.

Comment: Você me sugeriria algo para tentar descobrir o que de fato está acontecendo?